# from data get converted into uppercase at the time of saving

Tags: forms

I have big drupal form and when the form get save, at that time I need all form data should be converted into upper case and then should get save. Please guide me to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Different Solutions are discussed below:-

1.) You can attach a handler on submit event and then convert all form data to upper case using JavaScript function [String toUpperCase()] and then send the data.

2.)You can attach a handler on every field like onblur() or onchange() and write a common function for all handers to take the field data and convert to upper case right away.

3.) Third one you can do is to take data as it is and then on your server side code after taking data convert it to upper case using the function available in server side language you are using before storing into the database.